# Unable to bind to WINDOW_SERVICE from an android platform app

Tags: android, android-ndk, platform, android-build

I have an android platform app similar to input command where it binds to IWindowManager and inject key inputs.

I placed this code under external/vncagent folder. I was able to build it and I have a shell script that invokes the main class like am script does.

I am getting following exception when I run it. Same code in input (i.e frameworks/base/cmds/input) seems to work fine.

The exception I am getting is:

```
android.os.RemoteException: Unknown binder error code. 0xfffffff7
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
        at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.getService(ServiceManagerNative.java:120)
        at android.os.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:55)
        at mycom.service.vncapp.VNCController.getWinManager(VNCController.java:109)
        at mycom.service.vncapp.VNCController.sendKeyEvent(VNCController.java:120)
        at mycom.service.vncapp.VNCController.processCmd(VNCController.java:148)
        at mycom.service.vncapp.VNCController.access$200(VNCController.java:29)
        at mycom.service.vncapp.VNCController$InjectInput.run(VNCController.java:237)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is the code that invokes it.

```
    private synchronized IWindowManager getWinManager()
    {
        if (null == m_winManager)
        {
            try
            {
                m_winManager = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
            }
            catch(Throwable exp)
            {

            }
        }
        return m_winManager;
    }
```

After googling, I figured I need to sign my app with platform certificate. I added LOCAL_CERTIFICATE to my Android.mk file. That didn't make any difference.

My app follows the same model as standard platform input command and is being built as part of platform. Still my app is not able to get to IWindowManager.

Below is my Android.mk file

```
# Copyright 2008 The Android Open Source Project
#
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)
LOCAL_MODULE := vncagent
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)

#ALL_PREBUILT += $(TARGET_OUT)/bin/vncagent
$(TARGET_OUT)/bin/vncagent : $(LOCAL_PATH)/vncagent | $(ACP)
    $(transform-prebuilt-to-target)
```

Once the jar is built, I am pushing the jar and a shell script to target boards /data/mycom/vnc folder and launching it from an adb shell.

Edits on 4/30/2013: 
I gave up on this approach (i.e. building J2SE type jar and invoking the main class). The code compiles, but fails to bind to remote binder. Instead I created a Android service and wrapped this logic invokable through Intents. I have to build it as part of Android platform sources as I am using classes from private apis. I made lot of progress this way.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried getting this token the way usual apps do? (i.e. through getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)). I think that you have a problem accessing the ServiceManager for some reason, and maybe, in your case, you don't really need to

Comment: You need access to Context for that to work. This is J2SE style class with main() method. My app is neither an activity nor a Service.